# Semantic Kernel: The integration of chat and text completion services into the context does not utilize the models as expected

Tags: azure-openai, semantic-kernel

I'm developing an Azure Function and I've integrated SK to it injecting the kernel as seen in many starter projects.

```cs
//Microsoft Semantic Kernel configuration build
var skBuild = Kernel.Builder
                    .WithLoggerFactory(loggerFactory)
                    .WithAzureTextEmbeddingGenerationService("text-embedding-ada-002", azureOpenAIOptions.Endpoint, azureOpenAIOptions.ApiKey)
                    .WithAzureTextCompletionService("gpt-35-turbo-instruct", azureOpenAIOptions.Endpoint, azureOpenAIOptions.ApiKey)
                    .WithAzureChatCompletionService("gpt-35-turbo", azureOpenAIOptions.Endpoint, azureOpenAIOptions.ApiKey)                        
                    .WithMemoryStorage(memoryStore)
                    .Build();
```

Even I specified different models for each searvice

```cs
.WithAzureTextCompletionService("gpt-35-turbo-instruct",... ,...)
```

and

```cs
.WithAzureChatCompletionService("gpt-35-turbo",... ,...)
```

SK is only using the model specified for chat completion service.
What I'm expecting is to SK uses the correct model depending on implementation.

For example:
**gpt-35-turbo-instruct** when implementing

```cs
var result = await kernel.RunAsync(context, skill["Joke"]);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

and **gpt-35-turbo** when implementing

```cs
var chat = chatCompletionService.CreateNewChat("You are an AI assistant that helps people find information.");
        chat.AddMessage(AuthorRole.User, "Hi, what information can you provide for me?");
    
        string response = await chatCompletionService.GenerateMessageAsync(chat, new ChatRequestSettings());
        Console.WriteLine(response);
```

I'm missing something?